# Need help sorting an array of structures in C using qsort

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct, qsort

I have this struct.

```
struct Transport
{
   int id;
   float Price;
};
```

Here I read the data into and array of structs.

```
void read (struct Transport **Car, int *m)
{
    int i;
    printf("Insert total number of cars: ");
    scanf("%d",m);
    *Car=(struct Transport*) malloc ((*m)*3*sizeof(struct Transport));               

    for(i=1; i<=*m; i++)
    {
       (*Car)[i].id=i;
       printf("Price: ");
       scanf("%f",&(*Car)[i].Price);
       printf("\n");
    }
}
```

And here is the display function.

```
void display(struct Transport *Car,int m)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=m; i++)
    {
        printf("Entry #%d: \n",i);
        printf("Price: %2.2f\n",(Car+i)->Price);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Now here is the problem.I must sort the data by the Price field. So far I've tried this, but it does nothing.

```
int struct_cmp_by_price(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    struct Transport *ia = (struct Transport *)a;
    struct Transport *ib = (struct Transport *)b;
    return (int)(100.f*ia->Price - 100.f*ib->Price);
}
```

Here is how the main looks like.

```
int main()
{
    int m;
    struct Transport *Car;
    read(&Car,&m);
    qsort(Car, m, sizeof(struct Transport), struct_cmp_by_price);
    display(Car,m);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `qsort(Car,` --> `qsort(Car+1,` or `for(i=1; i<=*m` --> `for(i=0; i<*m`

Comment: Array indices start at 0 in C

Comment: Sorting against the Car+1 does not fix the off the end of the array adds.  Change the for loops.

Comment: that worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: @MichaelDorgan It is secured three times as necessary. `malloc ((*m)*3*sizeof(struct Transport));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- You allocate too much memory in `read()`, and you do not need to cast the return value of `malloc()` in C, but you should check for allocation failure. you should instead use:

  ```
  *Car = calloc(*m, sizeof(struct Transport));
  if (*Car == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory for %d structures\n", *m);
      exit(1);
  }
  ```
- You should not use `read` as a function name because it is the name of a system call and may conflict with the standard library use of that function. Use `readTransport`.
- indexes are `0` based in C.  Instead of `for(i=1; i<=*m; i++)`, use:

  ```
  for (i = 0; i < *m; i++)
  ```
- The comparison function cannot use the subtraction trick. As a matter of fact, the subtraction trick can only be used for integer types **smaller** than `int`. Use this instead:

  ```
  int struct_cmp_by_price(const void *a, const void *b) {
      const struct Transport *ia = a;
      const struct Transport *ib = b;
      return (ia->Price > ib->Price) - (ia->Price < ib->Price);
  }
  ```
- You should test the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid input. The `Price` members are left uninitialized in case of conversion failure, which leads to undefined behavior, unless you use `calloc()`, but the result is still meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using two separate structs, to make pointer operations easier to handle.

Something like this gives the right idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int id;
    float price;
} transport_t;

typedef struct {
    transport_t *Cars;
    int numcars;
} Cars_t;

Cars_t *initialize_struct(void);
void read(Cars_t *Car);
void display(Cars_t *Car);
int price_cmp(const void *x, const void *y);

int 
main(void) {
    Cars_t *Car;

    Car = initialize_struct();

    read(Car);

    printf("Before:\n");
    display(Car);

    qsort(Car->Cars, Car->numcars, sizeof(transport_t), price_cmp);

    printf("\nAfter:\n");
    display(Car);

    free(Car->Cars);
    free(Car);

    return 0;
}

void
read(Cars_t *Car) {
    int i, count = 0;

    printf("Insert total number of cars: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &(Car->numcars)) != 1) {
        printf("Invalid entry\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    Car->Cars = calloc(Car->numcars, sizeof(transport_t));
    if (Car->Cars == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Issue allocating memory for %d members", Car->numcars);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= Car->numcars; i++) {
        Car->Cars[count].id = i;
        printf("Car id %d\n", Car->Cars[count].id);

        printf("Price: ");
        scanf("%f", &(Car->Cars[count].price));

        count++;

        printf("\n");
    }
}

void
display(Cars_t *Car) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < Car->numcars; i++) {
        printf("Car id: %d, Car price: %2.2f\n", 
                Car->Cars[i].id, Car->Cars[i].price);
    }
}

Cars_t
*initialize_struct(void) {
    Cars_t *Car;

    Car = malloc(sizeof(*Car));
    if (Car == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", "Issue allocating memory for structure");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    Car->Cars = NULL;
    Car->numcars = 0;

    return Car;
} 

int
price_cmp(const void *x, const void *y) {
    const transport_t *car1 = x;
    const transport_t *car2 = y;

    if (car1->price > car2->price) {
        return +1;
    } else if (car1->price < car2->price) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```